# Remove pixel less than specified transparency

Tags: photoshop

I have a transparent image which i want to make a texture for web.  I want to place this on a coloured DIV which can be changed to achieve the same texture in different colors.

The problem I'm having it the transparent texture is to dark when placed on top of a coloured surface. I can modify the transparency of the texture but thats makes the texture grey.

My question "Is there a way to remove pixels under under a specified level of transparency?"

For example can i remove all pixels which are 20% Opacity or less?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "remove pixels"? What should happen to pixels less than 20% opacity - should they become black? white? 100% transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would suggest removing those pixels in Photoshop. You can always write simple script, which would read the pixels, and change all with alpha smaller then x to 0.

[read pixel value in bmp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296059/read-pixel-value-in-bmp-file)

(you would need to change from 24bit to 32 bit, since RGBA is 32 bit)

Comment: no you could not :P But you could manually remove all colors of certain values like in here:
http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15495/how-do-i-select-all-pixels-that-match-an-exact-color-value-in-adobe-photoshop . Generally, that might be a better place to ask photoshop related questions if you do not wish for programming-related answers

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place for graphic related questions

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I have achieved an simmary effect by creating a layer mask out of the texture. This seems to make the texture brighter without make it grey.