# BMP Char Array to file c/c++

Tags: arrays, save, bmp

Below is a scenario:

Client is written in C (ARM compiler) and Server is written in C#.

Server sends BMP (bitmap) byte array to client over TCP/IP and client saves it locally in file without changing anything.

Client receives and saves it successfully but image color changes.

Anyone can help me why image color has been changed?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296059/read-pixel-value-in-bmp-file) "windows stores the color values as (B, G, R) triples, not (R, G, B)."

Comment: Pls share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was on server while reading image, here is the solution:

System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(ImageFile,true);

I was using this one

System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(ImageFile);