# Loaded 2D texture is not binding itself to a QUAD

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I've loaded a texture's ID into the `tex` variable, but when I bind the texture with this ID just before drawing a QUAD (seen in code below inside the `renderScene` function surrounded by the `xxxxxxxxx...` comments),  no texture is getting applied to the QUAD; it remains colorless. No error messages either.

I've included all the texture-related things I've written in my program.

What else do I need to add/change?

```
#include<windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// (...)



GLuint loadBMP_custom(const char * imagepath);
GLuint tex = loadBMP_custom("texture.bmp");



GLuint loadBMP_custom( const char * imagepath )
{

   GLuint texture;

   int width, height;

   unsigned char * data;

   FILE * file;

   file = fopen( imagepath, "rb" );

   if ( file == NULL ) return 0;

   width = 256;
   height = 256;
   data = (unsigned char *)malloc( width * height * 3 );

   fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
   fclose( file );

  for(int i = 0; i < width * height ; ++i)
  {
    int index = i*3;
    unsigned char B,R;
    B = data[index];
    R = data[index+2];

    data[index] = R;
    data[index+2] = B;

  }



  glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
  glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE );
  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );


  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR );
  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT );
  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT );
  gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );
  free( data );

  return texture;
}



// (...)



void renderScene(void)
{

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    // Reset transformations
    glLoadIdentity();
    // Set the camera
    gluLookAt(  posX, 1.0f, posZ,
            posX+vlx, posY+vly,  posZ+vlz,
            0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f);




    // xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f (0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(-100.0f, -0.02f, -100.0f);
        glTexCoord2f (0.0, 1.0);
        glVertex3f(-100.0f, -0.02f,  100.0f);
        glTexCoord2f (1.0, 1.0);
        glVertex3f( 100.0f, -0.02f,  100.0f);
        glTexCoord2f (1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f( 100.0f, -0.02f, -100.0f);
    glEnd();

    // xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


    // [Also display 3D blocks in space besides the above QUAD, which serves as ground]

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();

}

//(...)

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    // (...)

    glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D) ;

    glutMainLoop();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: That's now how you load a DIB (Device Independent Bitmap). There's a stupid complicated header you have to deal with first.

Comment: Could you provide a link how to do that?

Comment: Not really, but I can tell you to look into an image loading library if you don't want a major headache. stb is popular and lightweight.

Comment: Do you see an untextured quad, or nothing at all? If it's not clear, set the background color to something other than black.

Comment: @Reto untextured quad.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your method to load a BMP file is incorrect: even if you know how big the image is (256x256), you would still need to skip ahead to the pixel data part (usually 54 bytes, which is the usual size of the header).

So now you could write your own importer by reading the official spec over here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

...Or also find many implementations on the web such as the one mentioned in this question: [C++: Read bitmap wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548804/c-read-bitmap-wrong)

Unless you find some easy-to-plug header(s)-only library, I would personally go against using a library to specifically deal with BMP files since it introduces extra dependencies for something quite easy to roll on your own (and at the same time, learn how to implement a simple file loader).

Comment: This can't be the only problem. Failing to skip the header would just shift the data by 18 pixels. The OP is saying that the result is not textured at all.